# params[:page] in will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

Gem `will_paginate` is used in our Rails controller:

```
 @module_actions = @module_actions.page(params[:page]).per_page(30)
```

Here what's the use of `params[:page]`? Does 0 of `params[:page]` mean displaying the first page of the `@module_actions` (there are 30 records on one page)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here page means the page number you want to view. Each page consists of some sprecific number of records which you can either set or use default. The range for page starts from 1 and can go to any further. If you have 100 records for `@module_actions` then see below output.

```
@module_actions = @module_actions.page(1).per_page(30) # 1-30 records
@module_actions = @module_actions.page(2).per_page(30) # 31-60 records
@module_actions = @module_actions.page(3).per_page(30) # 61-90 records
@module_actions = @module_actions.page(4).per_page(30) # 91-100 records
@module_actions = @module_actions.page(5).per_page(30) # empty array
```

And if you try to access records with page 0 you will get an error.

```
@module_actions = @module_actions.page(0).per_page(30) # Throws RangeError: invalid page: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The `params[:page] = 0` won't going to work. For displaying first page, it should be `params[:page] = 1` i.e the link should be

```
 localhost/something?page=1
 localhost/something?page=2
```

by default, even if you remove `?page=1` it will show first page content i.e

```
localhost/something?page=1
```

is same as

```
localhost/something
```